# Nodejs ember-precompile throwing TypeError

Tags: node.js, ember.js, precompile

For my emberjs application I wish to precompile my Handlebar templates but running Nodejs ember-precompile module from the terminal:

```
ember-precompile src/templates/*.handlebars -f public/js/templates.js
```

throws this TypeError error:

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'appendFileSync'
    at write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-precompile/bin/ember-precompile:25:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-precompile/bin/ember-precompile:32:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-precompile/bin/ember-precompile:31:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-precompile/bin/ember-precompile:36:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
```

What could cause the: TypeError: Object # has no method 'appendFileSync' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also faced the same issues , when i try to update Handlebars to the latest version
I did the following steps.

- Step 1: update your node server to latest.
- Step 2: Restart your system.

This works for me.